# Past perfect tense confusion

Tags: past-perfect

Here is the sentence.

“I had not made a decison yet, when they asked me what degree in college ***will*** (emphasised text) I pursue.

First question: Is it ok to use the word “will” in this context? I mean, its a future word right?

On a different topic, can the past perfect be only used when stating an activity in the past with **another activity in the past?** or can it be used **without an accompanying activity in the past?** or could the accompanying activity be replaced by a specific date or duration?

For example:

Example 1: I had studied last night. - ***Simple past or past perfect?***

Example 2: I had studied in college in the 1990’s - ***Simple past or past perfect?***

Comment: You can use *would* in that context, but it should come after the word "I", not before it.

Comment: 'Will' is a 'future word', but you are reporting a question asked in the past. Use 'will' when quoting the exact words _They asked "What degree will you pursue?"_ but not in reported speech _They asked what degree I would pursue._